# Optional dependencies in OSGI SCR framework

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, apache-felix

I am using the SCR framework in an OSGI felix platform to inject service references in my Components. This works great, except for optional dependencies. So if I have two components Foo and Bar, where Foo is given below:

```
@Component
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    @Reference(cardinality=ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_UNARY)
    Bar bar;

    public void bindBar(Bar bar) {
        log.info("bar bound: "+bar);
    }
    public void unbindBar(Bar map) {
        log.info("bar unbound: "+bar);
    }

    @override
    public void fooHello() {
        log.info("Hello, this is an implementation of Foo");
    }
}
```

this works, as long as the bundle defining the interface of Bar is deployed in my OSGi platform. If no Bar implementation component is activated in the platform, SCR is still happy and will activate my FooImpl component, ofcourse without reference to any Bar implementation. However, if the Bar interface is not deployed in the platform, SCR crashes during activation of my component, likely due to an exception from the inspection of my component via reflection, but I could not determine that definitively.

So, is there a way to deploy an OSGI bundle with optional dependencies that are not present in the platform that include SCR Components that have optional references to interfaces coming from these optional OSGi dependencies?

Comment: "SCR crashes" << I very much doubt that! What actually happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSGi dependencies can be used to inject *implementations* of some types, like `BarImpl` class implementing `Bar` interface which can be injected to `@Reference Bar bar` field. Optional dependencies mean that your OSGi component can use some service, but doesn't require it to work.

However, if OSGi doesn't know type you are trying to use as a field, you will get an exception and it is a valid behaviour. You simply can't use a class if its field has unknown type - and its true not only for OSGi but for Java in general.

A good approach here is to split bundle containing `Bar` implementation to two bundles:

- `bar-api` containing `Bar` interface,
- `bar-impl` containing OSGi service `BarImpl`.

`bar-api` is still required by `FooImpl`, but `bar-impl` is truly optional and disabling it in the Felix console won't break referencing components.

Comment: I have the split between api bundle, and implementation bundle, but with many optional dependencies, I still need all the api bundles. In this case, I have a generic component that is used in various, unrelated projects. I will try to find another split of the functions over classes and/or bundles.

Comment: Java class resolution is slightly less strict then you say: static methods will work, even if not all fields can be resolved. Imports of non-used packages are allowed, and fields that are not instantiated, can have non-resolved by them self. I hope(d) to find a solution that does not require all interfaces to be present in the platform.